# Selecting date from Datepicker using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Hi i am trying to select date in Datepicker in Selenium.

The Date picker has only day and month.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

[handle-calender-in-selenium-webdriver](http://learn-automation.com/handle-calender-in-selenium-webdriver/)